# Increase key days every 24 hours

Tags: redis

I could increase key "days" by command

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> set days 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> incr days
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> get days
"2"
```

How could I augment it automatically every 24 hours?

Comment: You would need to set up a cron or something to do that.

Comment: but crontab is a shell command @TheDude

Comment: Shell command can call redis-cli to do the job: `redis-cli incr days`

Comment: try using Distributed Task Queue like celery

Comment: impressive, could you please leave an answer. @Saeed

Comment: @Painter hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add celery conf, [read doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html). Somthing like this:

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('allunac', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

I choose redis for broker, because you work with it in your project, but you can choose another broker like RabbitMQ, [read doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#id3).

Because you need a task  at regular intervals you need celery beat too, [read doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#id1).

Add your task:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.core.cache import cache
from celery.decorators import periodic_task

@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=30))
def redis_add():
    if not cache.get('days'):
        cache.set('days', 1)  # set initial value
    else:
        cache.incr('days', 2)  # increase by 2
```

Run celery with beat:

```
celery -A proj worker -l info -B
```

**CELERY LOG**

[image]

**REDIS**

[image]